# What happen when move=null in camel route?

Tags: spring, apache-camel

In my Spring Camel app, I try to move or delete a file base on the `destinationFolder` property. If `destinationFolder=null`, I want the file to be deleted. If `destinationFolder!=null`, I want the file to be moved to `destinationFolder`.

```
String destinationFolder;

//In the Camel routeBuilder:
from("file://C:/folder1?move=" + destinationFolder)
```

What will happen in destinationFolder is null? Does the file get move to default location?

When I set destinationFolder=null, I see the file is deleted in folder1.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the move option then the file component will move the file, you cannot set it to `null` and then have it automatic delete the file. By default the file is moved to a folder named `.camel`.

So either set delete=true or set move to some folder name to move the files.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should know when to use "move", "delete" &"noop" and how it will works in Apache camel

Note :1) If your destination path is not existed then file will delete automatically.
Note :2) If you are not used "noop=true" in Camel URL then file file will delete(if your destination path is null)

Reference : - [enter link description here](https://camel.apache.org/file2.html)

Basic Test Code:

```
    import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

    import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;

    public class SFTPTest {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            DefaultCamelContext ctx = null;

            try{

                ctx = new DefaultCamelContext();

                ctx.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {

                    @Override

                    public void configure() throws Exception {

String filepath = "file:///camelexample/?fileName=test.txt&move=null";

                        from(filepath)

                              .log("File processed");

                    }

                });

                ctx.start();

                Thread.sleep(5000);

                ctx.stop();

            }catch (Exception e){

          System.err.println("Exception is : "+e.getLocalizedMessage());

            }finally {

                try{

                    ctx.stop();

                }catch (Exception e){

                   System.err.println("Exception is : "+e.getLocalizedMessage());

                }

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: In your link https://camel.apache.org/file2.html, I didn't see anywhere that they said if destination path is null, the file will be deleted. Can you point out where in the document do they said that? I just want to confirm.

Comment: They didn't mention any where in the document basically it will delete the file if destination path is null. I shared the link for your future reference.

Thank you